# Find partial derivative at point $(0,0)$ of $(x^2-y^2)/(x^2+y^2)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

It's a bit wierd question but I have to ask it.

$$ \text{Let }\space f(x, y) =
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{x^2-y^2}{x^2 + y^2},  & \text{if $(x, y) \ne (0,0)$} \\
0, & \text{if $(x, y) = (0, 0)$}  \\
\end{cases}$$

The following question is:

> Calculate the partial derivatives of f at the points where they exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously the partial derivatives exist at $(x,y) \not = (0,0)$, as it's a rational function and the denominator is never zero. Now to find the partial derivatives at $(0,0)$ you have:

$$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{f(x,0) - f(0,0)}{x} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\frac{x^2 - 0^2}{x^2 + y^2} - 0}{x} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac 1x = \infty $$

$$\lim_{y \to 0}\frac{f(0,y) - f(0,0)}{y} = \lim_{y \to 0} \frac{\frac{0^2 - y^2}{0^2 + y^2} - 0}{x} = \lim_{y \to 0} -\frac 1y = -\infty $$

Therefore the function has partial derivatives at every single point except the origin.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Why the limit gives infinity?

Comment: @Python241820 It's well-known that $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac 1x = \infty$. To understand try to divide $1$, by something arbitrarily small.

Answer (score 0):

Where is your problem? You have to use the definition. For $(x,y)\neq(0,0)$ the partial derivate is obvious and for $(x,y)=(0,0)$ you have to compute
$$
\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f((0,0)+h(1,0))-f(0,0)}h\text{ and }
\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f((0,0)+h(0,1))-f(0,0)}h.
$$
To be able to plug in the definition of $f$ you can assume $h\neq 0$.

If the first limit exists, it is by definition $\partial_1 f(0,0)$ and if the second limit exists, it is by definition $\partial_2 f(0,0)$.