# Second Partial Derivative of a piecewise function at point (0, 0)

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative, piecewise-continuity

I know how to get the first partial derivative of a piecewise function at a certain point but I'm unsure how to get the second one.

I'm trying to do it for the following function:

$f(x,y) = \begin{cases}
        \frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2} & \text{if } (x,y) \neq (0,0)\\
        0 & \text{if } (x,y) = (0,0)
\end{cases}$

I want to calculate the following partial derivatives:
$\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial y}(0,0)$ and  $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y \partial x}(0,0)$

I think it's:
$\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial y}(0,0) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,h) - \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0)}{h}$

I don't know how I should go about calculating this though.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find partial derivative at point $(0,0)$ of $(x^2-y^2)/(x^2+y^2)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2501104/find-partial-derivative-at-point-0-0-of-x2-y2-x2y2) Since there are not even *first* partial derivatives at $(0,0)$, there are no *second* ones.

Comment: Note that the function is not even continuous along the axes.